# SSH hangs on Mac OS X Big Sur 11.2 when connecting with domain, not with IP

Tags: ssh, mac

Since updating to Big Sur I've had problems using ssh. Running `ssh username@my.domain.com` simply hangs, printing nothing at all. Running `ssh -v username@my.domain.com` gives

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to my.domain.com port 22.
```

There are two solutions that I've found. The first is that connecting with the ip adress (which I found by running `ping my.domain.com`) like `ssh username@123.12.12.12` works. Also running `ssh username@my.domain.com -o ProxyCommand='nc %h %p'` works. Setting

```
Host *
 IPQoS lowdelay throughput
```

in /etc/ssh/ssh_config does not work though as [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343569/ssh-from-my-mac-hangs-after-authenticating-anywhere-regardless-of-app-its-def) question said it would. I have also tried unsetting SSH_AUTH_SOCK to no avail.

What is the problem? Is there some way of solving it that does not require aliasing ssh to ssh -o ProxyCommand='nc %h %p' or looking up the ip address whenever I want to ssh?

Comment: It might be an IPv4 vs IPv6 issue. Try forcing IPv4 with `ssh -4 username@my.domain.com` and see if that connects.

Comment: Nope, does not help unfortunately.

Comment: I don't know of a way to get `ssh` to be more specific about what's happening at the network layer, so if I were troubleshooting this the next thing I'd do would be to use `tcpdump` or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) to look at outgoing traffic on port 22, and see what's different between connecting via name vs. via IP number.

Comment: Right, I tried tcpdump and the answer is that there is no traffic whatsoever on port 22 when I try with name and it freezes. However, one time it just worked! I have not been able to reproduce it though. It seems that almost every time ssh fails to establish a connection, but once in a blue moon it manages to do so. After it worked I exited, changed nothing and tried again, and again, and again but it won't connect again.

Comment: Are there multiple IPs associated with that name? Try dscacheutil -q host -a my.domain.com`. Also, while it's hung trying to connect, open another terminal and run `netstat -an | sed -n '1,2p; /[.]22 /p'` and see what it says about this connection it's allegedly trying to make.

Comment: I think you are missing an argument on dscacheutil? Anyway, installing a newer version of openssh from homebrew and using that instead of the apple default seems to have fixed it. For science I'll try to run netstat tonight and see what I find though

Comment: You're right, it should be `dscacheutil -q host -a name my.domain.com`. (and I messed up the backticks, too. Oops.)

Comment: Aha, I'll try it when I get home. Thanks

Comment: Installing openssh via homebrew seems to have fixed the system ssh as well, I can no longer reproduce the hanging...